# Tool tip not coming next to text area

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to add a tooltip next to text area.
But tooltip is coming below text area as shown in image[image: tool tip actual position]

Here is the code which I have written

```
<div className="form-group row">
  <label className="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Player Account Names: </label>
  <div className="col-sm-8">
    <textarea
      id="noteText"
      style={{ padding: "8px 10px", lineHeight: "17px", height: "125px" }}
      rows={3}
      className="form-control"
      name="accountNames"
      value={this.state.dropBonusState.accountNames}
      onChange={this.droupBonusChange}
    />
    <span
      className="fas fa-question-circle"
      onMouseEnter={() => "Enter value"}
      onMouseLeave={() => ""}
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

I also tried the following

```
     <div data-tip="This is tool tip">
```

But it is not working.
Tool tip should come in the green box in image.

Comment: please add any additional relevant styles. (Looks like a styling issue)

Comment: If I remember correctly, the form-control class will use up 100% width so your tooltip won't fit into the row.

Comment: Hi even if I remove className="form-control" tooltip and text area are not coming side by side.

Comment: @pravinkottawar try reducing the padding. It's probably throwing the positioning out. Remove it first and see if it makes a difference to the position. If it does, slowly increase it.